# Ender 3 Pro & BLTouch clone issue

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, bed-leveling, bltouch

I just installed a BLTouch clone on my Ender 3 Pro with a standard 1.1.4 board. The sensor seems to work but is giving me problems.

I used the Teaching Tech tutorial on YouTube to install it, but after I had issues with the Marlin 1.1.9 bug fix. After that and some more reading about the issues and the clone sensors, I removed the capacitor next to the Z-stop but was still having issues (it just wouldn’t stop at the bed). Thus I went back to the original Ender 3 Pro firmware, released by Creality on January 20th.

As said, the sensor now is working, but when auto homing it doesn’t move an inch on the Z-axis. Instead, as soon as it should home on Z, it directly thinks it has hit home. See this clip I made:

I’m hoping any of you have a clue what I’m doing wrong, or how to fix this.

Comment: Am I correct to see a lot of blue light emitted by the sensor? That usually indicates that there is something wrong with the cable. Note, having owned about 5 clone sensors, it was a blessing to use the actual product, the clones are underperforming in my experience.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I thought I had wired it correctly, but I will recheck the wires and report back!